# Div fill remaining horizontal space

Tags: css, html

I have this following code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>this</li>
        <li>width</li>
        <li>is</li>
        <li>dynamic.</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="something">
        <span>so is this</span>
        <table>because of this table.</table>
    </div>

    <div class="fill">
        <span>and so is this. but this guy needs to fill the remaining width.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXCSG.png)

These 3 items - ul and 2 divs - are aligned side by side, and as you can see, they have dynamic widths. I have to make these 3 items fit inside div.parent, which width is fixed at 1200px.

Currently, I'm using 'float: left;' to align these 3 items side-by-side, and I can use 'display: inline-block;' if necessary [works perfectly]. But I've tried to use some tricks with 'display: table;' for the parent and 'display: table-cell;' for these 3 items, without success.

I need to fill this remaining space on the black div, which is the 'div.fill'. Any ideas?

EDIT2: http://jsfiddle.net/cAs9t/

Comment: Try using this in your css: `.fill{width:100%}`

Comment: Please post the related css as well or even better make a fiddle.

Comment: I've tried, but it takes the width from .parent, not the remaining width..

Comment: try `.fill{display: block}`

Comment: 'display: block;' doesn't works as well.'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cAs9t/

Comment: It would be interesting to see this solved using your approch Paulo, however I think using `%` on `width` and dropping `float:left` would be a better solution. So I would suggest you have `.parent{width:100%}` then divide width of each div inside `.parent` by 3 (since you have three divs inside parent)... our you can do the calculation based on the content of each div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cAs9t/2/)

Just add

```
div.fill { float: none; overflow: hidden; }
```

Where `float: none` removes the floating (you can also avoid applying `float: left` to `.fill`), and `overflow: hidden` (or anything different than `visible`) prevent floating elements from overlapping `.fill`.

Other ways:

- You could use `display: table-cell` and `display: table`, but you couldn't specify which element should grow to fill all remaining space.
- But if you want full control and want to distribute remaining spaces in a more complex way, you should use [Flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

Comment: Works perfectly with float:none and overflow: hidden, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PauloMu you should accept Oriol's answer if it suits you! That's the whole point of SO.

Comment: I would not have thought to use overflow:hidden as a solution (it works great!). Can someone explain, in a little more detail, why this property causes this effect?

Comment: @DBK Maybe you will understand what's happening if you see http://jsfiddle.net/Q4p8C/

Answer (score 2):

I made the parent `display:table` and the 3 children as `display:table-cell`. Now all 3 children fill the width of the parent and you don't need to float any of them. One advantage of this method is that you can utilize `vertical-align` and also avoid wrapping of blocks when the parent is shorter than the content. In a way, you get all the goodness of a `table`.

Υou can set the width of the first 2 children and leave the last without specifying width so that it will fill the parent container.

[**See this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cAs9t/3/).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but using 'display: table;' and 'display: table-cell' just dislocated the white space from div.fill to div.something. I guess it happens because the browser tries to equal the width from all 'display: table-cell' elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use display:table for the container and display:table-row for its direct children.

Set height:0 for the divs with variable height and height:auto for the div that should fill the remaining space.

If the container needs a fixed height, whether in pixels or %, you can add a single div with {overflow-y:auto; height:100%} to the horizontal filler and add content within there.

```
<div style="height:300px; border:1px solid red;padding:2px;">
  <div style="display:table; height:100%; width:100%;border: 1px solid blue;">
    <div style="display: table-row; height:0; padding:2px; background-color:yellow;">
        I take as much space as needed
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height:auto; padding:2px; background-color:green;">
      <div style="height:100%; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="height: 500px">My parent will fill the remaining space</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row; height:0; padding:2px; background-color:yellow;">
      <p>I take as much space as needed as well</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Flexbox solution

**Note:** Add flex vendor prefixes if required by your [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

```css
.parent {
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fill {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="menu" style="background: #6cf">
<li>this</li>
<li>width</li>
<li>is</li>
<li>dynamic.</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="something" style="background: #fd6">
<span>so is this</span>
<table>because of this table.</table>
  </div>
  <div class="fill" style="background: #5c5">
<span>and so is this. but this guy needs to fill the remaining width.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```